# Regex to find matches words that is in a line that doesn't start with

Tags: java, regex

I am really having a hard time creating a Regex that finds a word but if and only if it the line it is in does not start with --.

For example:

Look for word: if

```
-- check if //should not match
-- more random words if //should not match
check if //should match
```

I have tried using negative lookbehinds like:

```
(?<!-- .*)\bif\b
```

But I'm using JAVA and also, I cannot use quantifiers in lookbehinds.

If I try

```
(?<! -- )\bif\b
```

It does work on

```
-- if \\works
--  if \\does not work
```

I found out the usage of SKIP and F but, it seems JAVA does not cater these two.

Any advice on how can I deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `!line.startsWith("--") && line.matches("\\bif\\b")`?  Is there a good reason to make everything more complicated by insisting that you have to do everything with a regex?

Comment: Hi @ajb, I have a multiline text with multiple words to match. I already have a loop that loops through all the words I need to match. I'm using text.replaceall so that I do not have to split the whole text by \n and iterate through each line while iterating through each keyword I need to match.

Comment: @Takeshi The comment by ajb is spot on AFAIK.  The regex you would need would likely be complex, while using Java's string operations would be simple and easier to maintain.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I see. So then it should be better to just do a loop within a loop with a IF check, rather than one loop with a regex? Thanks.

Comment: You should only need a single loop if you're splitting the document on newline.  Check the start of each line and its contents and go from there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but I also have a list of words that I want to match (not just IF), thus, I would have a loop for the keywords and a loop that reads each line.

Comment: Depending on how few words you are trying to match, you could just use something like `line.matches("word1|word2|word3|...")`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sadly, I have a hundred different words to match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Java 8, you could do something like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!--).*if");
    Predicate<String> pred = s -> {return p.matcher(s).find();}; 
    Files.lines(Paths.get("files/input.txt"))
         .filter(pred).forEach(System.out::println);
```

It is called a [negative look ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how long your lines are, but you can use for example this ugly construction (of course number could be smaller):

```
(?m)(?<!^--.{0,99999999999999999})if
```

[EXAMPLE](http://fiddle.re/tw4pga)

Java allows some interval quantifiers in look behind and look ahead, but it just looks wrong :P however it works, at least it works for me in this example.

Another approach, if I you want to raplace all occurances, why not use capturing groups? like:

```
String[] examples = {"-- check if ",
        "-- more random words if ",
        "check if ", "-- f",
        "-- check if \n-- more random words if \ncheck if "};
for(String string : examples) {
    System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(?m)(?!^--)^(.*?)if","$1" + "replacement"));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Regex `(?m)(?!^--)^(.*)(if)` will match everything up to searched word and capture it into group 1, then in raplacement you can put it back into text. Not most efficient, but should work anyway.

Comment: Code like this makes me nervous.